# Cumulative sum of all transitions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this DataFrame

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                        'task':['A','B','C','D','A','B','D'],
                        'time':['2020-01-1','2020-01-2','2020-01-3','2020-01-4','2020-01-5','2020-01-6','2020-01-7']}) 
df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.time)
```

I want to find the total time between all tasks grouped by `id` something like this

```
   event total_time
0  A - B  2 Days   
1  B - C  1 Days   
2  C - D  1 Days   
3  B - D  1 Days
```

I just got till here

```
df2['time_diff'] = df2.groupby(df2.id)['time'].diff()
```

Which gives me this

```
   id task       time time_diff
0  1   A   2020-01-01 NaT      
1  1   B   2020-01-02 1 days   
2  1   C   2020-01-03 1 days   
3  1   D   2020-01-04 1 days   
4  2   A   2020-01-05 NaT      
5  2   B   2020-01-06 1 days   
6  2   D   2020-01-07 1 days
```

Now how can I group all this `time_diff` and add them up according to there `event`

Comment: How did you get 2 days for `A-B` in your example. What you want in the final is a column with the `A-B, B-C,` etc with the corresponding days?

Comment: As in the data frame if u see in 'id' 1 we have 1 A -B which took 1 day and again if we see id 2 we again see A - B consequently so both events took 1 day + 1 day  = 2 days.
But if we see the rest like B - C or C - D only comes once in id 1 but  not in id 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can simply `groupby` and concat:

```
df2['time_diff'] = df2.groupby(df2.id)['time'].diff()

df2["dir"] = df2.groupby("id")["task"].transform(lambda d: d.shift()+" - "+d)

print (df2)

   id task       time time_diff    dir
0   1    A 2020-01-01       NaT    NaN
1   1    B 2020-01-02    1 days  A - B
2   1    C 2020-01-03    1 days  B - C
3   1    D 2020-01-04    1 days  C - D
4   2    A 2020-01-05       NaT    NaN
5   2    B 2020-01-06    1 days  A - B
6   2    D 2020-01-07    1 days  B - D

print (df2.groupby("dir")["time_diff"].sum())

dir
A - B   2 days
B - C   1 days
B - D   1 days
C - D   1 days
Name: time_diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```